# WF4: How to setup a workflow to receive multiple messages

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

I want a workflow, which can receive multiple of the same message from a MSMQ.

Example:

```
Receive: CreateWorkflow (CanCreateInstance=True)
Do Something...
Parallel (CompletionCondition=ExitParallel)
    Parallel Branch 1
        Receive: Update (CanCreateInstance=False, Use correlation)
        Process...
    Parallel Branch 2
        Receive: Finish (CanCreateInstance=False, Use correlation)
        Set ExitParallel=True
```

I would like to have my workflow be able to receive multiple Update messages. However, in this setup, it can only receive 1. According to [this MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/51342d05-0ef6-4357-9c94-78db31a76431), this should work, but I never got this to work.

Is the solution to put an infinite while loop in Parallel Branch 1? Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to receive multiple update messages you will have to put that receive in a loop. The way you set it up right now the update is allowed once and the Parallel only waits for the second branch, with the Finish, to complete.

Comment: Putting the receive in a loop works. There's a possibility that another "Update" message comes while the the workflow is processing a previous "Update" message. In this case, the workflow is not on the Receive. Will the message get lost? Or does the message wait until the workflow goes back to the receive?

Comment: The workflow service has a AllowBufferedReceive property that allows you to put messages in a queue before they are processes and that will let you get back to the Receive and read the second request.